# Swift image slider/carousel UIPageViewController vs Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I found these examples of doing a images slider/carusel. One using a [UIPageViewController](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OopGGyHKHlU) and one using a [scrollview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaWnv5sRpho)

In my app I need to embedd a image slider inside a contentview for a VC, then also add click to enlarge to view the image in fullscreen as well. So what are the pros/cons for using a UIPageViewController or a scrollview?

Looking at the two examples they look like they behave the same beside the UIPageViewController showing dots/indicators

Comment: ScrollView allows you to zoom naturally (there are properties for it `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale`). However, for PageController, you have to do a scale-transform (`CGAffineTransformMakeScale`) on the controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a UIScrollView, (too much work/potential for bugs resetting the scrollView's contentOffset for sliding through the gallery smoothly).

When I've implemented a sliding image gallery before I used a UICollectionView. The collectionViewCell's bounds match the parent collectionView's, the cell contains an imageView pinned to the edges of the cell and the collectionView's scrollDirection is set to horizontal.

You can add a UIPageControl on top of the UICollectionView if you want, it's not necessarily an essential feature. As an alternative to using a UIPageControl I've added a UILabel to float above the screen coordinates of the UICollectionView and update its value based on the number of items and the currently displayed cell in the collectionView. E.g. 1/4 -> 2/4 etc.

Comment: Okey I will try to build it like that. But in order to add a "click to enable full screen" Should I segue to a another UIPageViewController that is in fullscreen?